# MySQL JOIN strange bahaviour

Tags: mysql, join

Assuming we have the following 2 tables

> Table: main

- id (Primary)
- ip ( varchar 255 )

> Table: sub

- sub_id ( Primary )
- main_id ( supposed to be the column i want to join with )
- ip

In main table, i have 1000 rows, and in table sub i have 10.000 rows.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `main` t1
RIGHT JOIN
  `sub` t2 ON t2.main_id = t1.id
```

Why the above query returns 1000 rows and not 10.000? I'm doing right join, and in the sub table i have 10.000 rows.

Also why phpmyadmin says?

> Current selection does not contain a unique column

Comment: The `right join` should be returning every row in the second table (`sub`) regardless of whether or not there is a match.  I think you might be making a mistake somewhere -- does your query have any other clauses, for instance?

Comment: List the name of the column you want to see, after the select rather than *. Maybe this will explain the PhpMyAdmin message.

Comment: Selecting specific columns, and not with * solves the problem even with the RIGHT JOIN. Any reason why this is happening? I dont understand

Comment: Most probably a bug on PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Can this be a reason - https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=maxrows#cfg_MaxRows ?

Comment: No because without asterisk (*) it loads 10.000 rows with no problem

Comment: Try to check this query with another mysql client tool.